# How to kill a command started over SSH - the SSH connection lost

Tags: ssh, timeout

If I use

```
timeout 10 ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes 1.1.1.1 'sleep 20' > 1.1.1.1.txt 2>&1 &
```

To give out a remote command on a server, and I kill the SSH connection after 10 seconds, then I can see that the `sleep 20` is still running on the server, but there is no SSH connection.

How can I kill the remote command after a timeout, say 10 seconds?

The remote machine is AIX 6.1 (or SLES) and no package is available for "timeout". My client is Ubuntu 10.03.

Comment: If you knew the PID of the command (I'm assuming you do, seeing as you can still see it running), you send it a `TERM` signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your remote server has a POSIX-compliant shell, the following should work:

```
ssh ...options... 'command & pid=$!; sleep 20; kill $pid'
```

Indeed the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) states about `$!`:

> Expands to the decimal process ID of the most recent background
>   command (see Lists) executed from the current shell. (For example,
>   background commands executed from subshells do not affect the value
>   of "$!" in the current shell environment.) For a pipeline, the
>   process ID is that of the last command in the pipeline.

If the remote system has job control, you can shorten it this way:

```
ssh ...options... 'command & sleep 20; kill %1'
```

Comment: +1 for the `kill %1` way; I've done that in some scripts in the past.

Comment: what does "kill %1" do? does it always kill the good process? what happensd if there are more processes sent to background with "&" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want still do it with just 'timeout' command, your remote execution command (ssh) should get a tty allocated, then timeout will even kill the remote call. Change your ssh command to have '-t' in it.